# Color Formating from pandas to excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with values and a condition according to previous filtering. I would like to print my dataframe in an excel and color the cell according to the filtering result (if *passed*: **green** and if *not_passed*: **red**). Here is an example code and how I would like it to turn out.

```
filename='example'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f"{filename}.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter")
workbook = writer.book
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [0,{'value': 3, 'filter': 'passed'}],
        [1,{'value': 4, 'filter': 'not_passed'}],
        [2,{'value': 2, 'filter': 'passed'}],
    ],
    columns=['col 1', 'col 2']
)
df['col 2'] = df['col 2'].apply(lambda x: x['value'])
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1")
green = workbook.add_format({"bg_color": "#C6EFCE", "font_color": "#006100"})
red = workbook.add_format({"bg_color": "#FFC7CE", "font_color": "#9C0006"})
worksheet = writer.sheets["Sheet1"]
writer.save()
```

[image: Example output]

Comment: Search around for `pd.DataFrame.style`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a for loop to check if the `filter value == 'passed'`
If it is, you can apply the green format to this cell, and Vice versa for Red using worksheet.write(row_index,column_index,value,format).

*Note that Pandas data frames use a different indexing method than Excel. Notably, Pandas starting at index=0, and Excel starting at index=1.*

```
filename='example'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f"{filename}.xlsx", engine="xlsxwriter")
workbook = writer.book
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [0,{'value': 3, 'filter': 'passed'}],
        [1,{'value': 4, 'filter': 'not_passed'}],
        [2,{'value': 2, 'filter': 'passed'}],
    ],
    columns=['col 1', 'col 2']
)
# df['col 2'] = df['col 2'].apply(lambda x: x['value'])
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Sheet1")

green = workbook.add_format({"bg_color": "#C6EFCE", "font_color": "#006100"})
red = workbook.add_format({"bg_color": "#FFC7CE", "font_color": "#9C0006"})

worksheet = writer.sheets["Sheet1"]

col_ind = 2

for row_ind in range(len(df)):
    value = df.iloc[row_ind, 1]
    
    if value['filter'] == 'passed':
        worksheet.write(row_ind+1,col_ind, value['value'], green)
    else:
        worksheet.write(row_ind+1,2col_ind, value['value'], red)

writer.save()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).